# How to turn Off react/react-in-jsx-scope rule?

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I'm using react 18 and eslint 8
Try to prevent missing React when using JSX (react/react-in-jsx-scope)
This rule was added to the .eslintrc.json

```
"plugins": ["react", "prettier"],
"rules": {
  "react/jsx-uses-react": "off",
  "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
 ...
```

But still see this error on start and build `'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope`

Comment: did you try restarting the eslint server

Comment: @J.Cutshall yes

Answer (score 0):

`package.json` also has `eslintConfig`. Try adding the rule there and check once. Also, I'd suggest maintaining only one `eslintConfig`. Either move the configuration from `.eslintrc.json` to `package.json` or other way around.

Comment: tried did't work.